# Как правильно взаимодействовать с атрибутами элементов в HTML через JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть в теле элемент `<marquee>` с атрибутами `id` и `scrollamount`. При изменение `scrollamount` напрямую в коде, скорость движения картинок меняется. При попытке изменить значение через функцию `faster()` с обращением `document.getElementById("stroka").scrollamount`, изменений не происходит. Подобное случается с другими элементами: по типу `<div>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function faster() {
      document.getElementById("stroka").scrollamount = "100";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <marquee id="stroka" scrollamount="6">
    <img src="IMAGES\cat.jpg">
    <img src="IMAGES\dog.jpg">
    <img src="IMAGES\leo.jpg">
    <img src="IMAGES\parrots.jpg">
  </marquee>
  <button type="button" onclick="faster()">Быстрее</button>
  <button type="button">Медленнее</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: «Как правильно взаимодействовать» — читать документацию. Например, если открыть документацию по [HTMLMarqueeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMarqueeElement), то можно увидеть, что свойства `scrollamount` у него не существует, зато есть `scrollAmount`

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, работает